# How to convert System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings from String to INT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have defined the following inside my web.config file:-

```
<add key="TechPageSize" value="20" />
```

But I m unable to reference this value inside my paging parameters as follow:-

```
var servers = repository.AllFindServers(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.Tag).ToPagedList(page, (Int32)System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"]);
```

and I will get an error that it can not change String to INT.

Any idea what is the problem ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
int techPageSize;
if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"], out techPageSize))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid TechPageSize in web.config");
}
```

[`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) has two effects:

- It converts the app setting to an integer and stores the result in `techPageSize`, if possible.
- If the value cannot be converted, the method returns `False`, allowing you to handle the error as you see fit.

PS: It suffices to use [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx), once you have imported the `System.Configuration` namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"])
```

This will error if the convert fails. You could use int.Tryparse in case it doesn't convert to an int, but the fact is this is a config setting and only you have control over this value - it's not user-submitted so catering for error would be overkill IMO.

Answer (score 4):

The result of

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"]
```

is a string, you can't just cast a string to int. Use Convert.ToInt32 or int.TryParse to get the integer value of the string.

```
int pagesize = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"]);
```

or

```
bool succeed = int.TryParse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"], out pagesize);
```